# how to get multipale search input php mysql

Tags: php

hi i am new to php mysql. I have created a form where the user can search the database, and the result depends on how the user fills in the form. form has 6 search fields. where user can choose / fill any of one or more fields to make his search. i have coded it as follows
php

```
<?php require_once('Connections/osrc.php'); ?>
<?php
$maxRows_search_result = 10;
$pageNum_search_result = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_search_result'])) {
  $pageNum_search_result = $_GET['pageNum_search_result'];
}
$startRow_search_result = $pageNum_search_result * $maxRows_search_result;

mysql_select_db($database_osrc, $osrc);
$propertyid = $_POST['propertyid'];
$offered = $_POST['offered'];
$property_type = $_POST['property_type'];
$beds = $_POST['beds'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$locality = $_POST['locality'];
$query_search_result = "SELECT * FROM osrc_data WHERE propertyid LIKE '%$propertyid%' OR offered LIKE '%$offered%' AND property_type LIKE '%$property_type%' AND beds LIKE '%$beds%' AND city LIKE '%$city%' AND locality LIKE '%$locality%' ";
$query_limit_search_result = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_search_result, $startRow_search_result, $maxRows_search_result);
$search_result = mysql_query($query_limit_search_result, $osrc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_search_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_result);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_search_result'])) {
  $totalRows_search_result = $_GET['totalRows_search_result'];
} else {
  $all_search_result = mysql_query($query_search_result);
  $totalRows_search_result = mysql_num_rows($all_search_result);
}
$totalPages_search_result = ceil($totalRows_search_result/$maxRows_search_result)-1;
?>
```

now when user It works but it shows all rows in database table. 
for example user fills up three fields beds, city, locality and rest of three are blank. 
search result page shows all rows in data base with all records.
pls help me to correct my codes. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated to the Problem: Please use the MySQLi Extension instead of the old MySQL Extension.

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with @VaaChar, you should be using mysqli or even better yet PDO.

You will have determine IF a value has been placed in a field and if so use it in your query. If no value was placed in the field ignore it in your query.

Something like this...

```
$sqlid = "";
$sqloffered = "";
$sqltype = "";
$sqlbeds = "";
$sqlcity = "";
$sqllocality = "";

if(isset($propertyid)) {
    $sqlid = " propertyid LIKE '%$propertyid%'";
}
if(isset($propertyid) && isset($offered)) {
    $sqloffered = " OR offered LIKE '%$offered%'"; 
}
if(!isset($propertyid) && isset($offered)) {
    $sqloffered = " offered LIKE '%$offered%'"; 
}
if(isset($property_type)) {
    $sqltype = " AND property_type LIKE '%$property_type%'";
}
if(isset($beds)) {
    $sqlbeds = " AND beds LIKE '%$beds%'";
}
if(isset($city)) {
    $sqlcity = " AND city LIKE '%$city%'";
}
if(isset($locality)) {
    $sqllocality = " AND locality LIKE '%$locality%'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM osrc_data WHERE {$sqlid}{$sqloffered}{$sqltype}{$sqlbeds}{$sqlcity}{$sqllocality} ";
```

Comment: @sachin - Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

When you build the sql query with (say) $propertyid empty, you get this :

.... LIKE '%%' ...,

which is like saying "anything". You must build your query only with the fields that have been filled.